# Buffon needle - variation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have a paper ruled with equally space lines of distance $d$. Let $X_l$ be the random variable which represents the number of line intersections for a given needle of length $l$. Recall that the expected value of is given by:

$\mathbb{E}(X_l)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\mathbb{P}(X_l=n)$. It is well known that: $\mathbb{E}(X_l)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\cdot\dfrac{l}{d}$.

I am curious if we have two joined segments of lengths $l_1$ and $l_2$, with $l=l_1+l_2$, which make an angle $\theta\in [0,\pi]$, is it true that the expected number of intersections between this linkage and the parallel lines is exactly $\mathbb{E}(X_l)=\dfrac{2l}{\pi d}$ (so it does not depend on the choice of the angle $\theta$ but only on the perimeter of the linkage $l=l_1+l_2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  This is a special case of the so-called [Buffon's noodle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_noodle), which replaces the straight “needle” with a “noodle” of any shape.

In addition to the Wikipedia article linked above (which contains a sketch of the proof), see the following article:

[Ramaley, J. F. “Buffon's noodle problem.” *American Mathematical Monthly* (1969): 916–918.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317945)